# How to handle delete mutations with optimistic UI in Apollo?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, apollo, vue-apollo

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-apollo.html#graphql-mutation-options-optimisticResponse

There's plenty of documentation and tutorials showing use of the mutation `update` and `optimisticResponse` properties involving adding things, but I haven't seen any involving deletions.

I'm not exactly sure how that code should look. With a create mutation, you want to add the new item to the Apollo cache via `update` and add a temporary copy to the UI using `optimisticResponse`. But with a deletion, it doesn't make sense to "show" the deletion since it's the absence of data.

This is what I've got in a method in my Vue component, which is partly correct:

```
async handleDelete(trackId: number) {
  const result = await this.$apollo.mutate({
    mutation: require('@/graphql/delete-tracks.gql'),
    variables: {
      ids: [trackId],
    },
    update: store => {
      const data: { getTracks: TrackList } | null = store.readQuery({
        query: getTracksQuery,
        variables: this.queryVars,
      });

      if (data && data.getTracks) {
        data.getTracks.data = data.getTracks.data.filter(
          (track: Track) => track.id !== trackId
        );
        --data.getTracks.total;
      }

      store.writeQuery({
        query: getTracksQuery,
        variables: this.queryVars,
        data,
      });
    },
    optimisticResponse: {},
  });

  console.log('result:', result);
},
```

I figured out that I basically need to remove the deleted item from the Apollo cache, and that part seems to work great. Though the visual removal doesn't happen immediately, since there's no `optimisticResponse`. That's the part I have absolutely no idea how to go about writing.

Comment: reminder to wrap everything in the update with a try catch since store.readQuery can fail if theres nothing in the cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it, it was much simpler than I thought. I just didn't quite understand how `optimisticResponse` came into play with `update`.

```
optimisticResponse: {
  __typename: 'Mutation',
  deleteTracks: [trackId],
},
```

So the `update` method will take this result from `optimisticResponse` and remove that track ID from the cache. `update` will be called a second time with the GraphQL server response, and the Apollo cache will be reconciled.